# Importing R model into h2o

Tags: r, h2o

I have already created model in R and saved the model in .rds file. I need to load that saved model in h2o. Can anybody suggest the way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `h2o.saveModel` and `h2o.loadModel` functions rather than the `base::save()` function in R.

The models in H2O are not stored in R memory, they are stored in the H2O cluster memory, so using `save()` is not sufficient to save H2O models.